# I could not establish mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I get an error when trying to install Mongodb. I downloaded and tried 3 different versions.
But I always get the following error. What should I do ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cby40.png)

```
Translate:This application does not work on your computer.
Contact your publisher to find a suitable version for your computer.
```

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Does your system meet the requirements at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/ ? Have you followed all the steps there?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.
I followed all the steps. https://eksiup.com/p/si145793ebwr

Comment: Including the "Windows 2012 Server and Windows 10 need KB2999226 to provide Universal C Runtime support for Windows." one?

Comment: I guess not included.

Comment: If I upload it, will it dissolve?

Comment: OK, then you *did not* follow all the steps on that page. I'm not sure what you mean by "dissolve", but you need to install that KB2999226 item as instructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/):

> Windows 2012 Server and Windows 10 need [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) to provide Universal C Runtime support for Windows.